# Looking for "^" symbol

Tags: symbols

What is the correct symbol for `^`  in math mode?
I can't type `^` as it appears as superscript symbol

Comment: You want it as superscript or not?

Comment: `\hat{}`, `\wedge`, `\textrm{\textasciicircum}`, `{}^{\wedge}`

Comment: Or `^{\wedge}` if you want the `^` to appear in superscript...